# How to reuse S3 image?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3

I uploaded images to S3 with carrier wave gem.(Ruby on Rails, Vue.js)

But I want to reuse uploaded image as a file.

I have no idea about how to reuse uploaded S3 images as a file.

To be specific,

I made a model "reaction"

and the image is saved as a column of "reaction".

I can reuse image object like @reaction.image
(@reaction is a "reaction"`s object)

No trial

I totally dont know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the image url from your table "Reaction". We can basically downloading an image located at a given URL and saved it as a file locally.

```
def download_aws_s3(url_aws_s3, filename)
  uri = URI(url_aws_s3)
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  File.open(filename, 'wb'){|f| f.write(response.body)}
end
```

You can use "open-uri" or "down" gem as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any other way to save it locally before uploading?